# Complex conjugate doubts

Tags: complex-numbers

$$
\frac{\bar{z}+i}{1-i\bar{z}}
$$

I wanted to know what is the conjugate to simplify the equation from above, i mean:

Would it be like this:
$$
\overline{(1-i\bar{z})}=1+i\bar{z}
$$
Or:
$$
\overline{(1-i\bar{z})}=1+iz
$$
since $\overline{\bar{z}}=z$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It would be the latter

Comment: Use `$\overline{1-i\bar z}$` to produce $\overline{1-i\bar z}$

Comment: Thanks , i already change it and thanks for the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\overline{(1-i\bar{z})}=1+iz
$$
is the correct way

So the fraction will now become

$$
\frac{z-i}{1+iz}
$$

Comment: i don t how you got that fraction, what i have been doing is multiplicating the original fraction for the denominator conjugate, i arrive to $\frac{i(1Im(z)+|z|^2+1)}{2Re(zi)+|z|^2+1}$ i don´t know what i have done wrong

Comment: The fraction that I have mentioned is just another version of the same expression. Now multiplying both numerator and denominator by the denominator of the original fraction will make the denominator real and hence simplify the expression.

Comment: Ok i get it, it´s just it seems such a strange answer to be the final part , couldn´t i find a relation betwen Im(z) and Re(zi) to simplify more ? $$\frac{i(2Im(z)+|z|^2+1)}{2Re(zi)+|z|^2+1}$$

Comment: No, it's pretty simplified to work with now actually. I haven't checked your calculations, but if that's what it is, that's what it is!

Comment: I had an error it´s actually $$ \frac{i(-2Im(z)+|z|^2+1)}{2Re(zi)+|z|^2+1} $$ and since Im(z)=b and Re(zi)=-b for z=a+bi we have that Im(z)=-Re(zi) so the fraction is actually equal to i.The funnny part is that if i consider $\overline{1-i\bar{z}}=1+i\bar{z}$ i get the same result, i am speechless